# Azure SQL Server Database View Permissions

Tags: sql-server, azure

I am connecting to my Azure SQL database using SQL Server Manager. I have created a view called `viw_Intake_Admin_Forms`. I am receiving a permissions error...

> SELECT permission was denied on the object 'viw_Intake_Admin_Forms'

...when trying to use the view in PHP. When I right click on the view, I do not see the properties selection to set the user permissions. How do I provide user permissions to this view? The user has select permissions on the table referenced in the view.

Comment: Is it possible you're connected to the database as a user who can create views but can't grant or deny permissions? Can you try in a query window `GRANT SELECT ON dbo.viw_Intake_Admin_Forms TO phpusername;`? Also, I have to ask, why the prefix `viw_` when just one more letter would have produced the much more readable `view_`?

Comment: The grant select resolved my issue. I'm wondering why the properties option is not available when right clicking on the view. This option is available for views for our local databases.

Comment: Not sure, could be the version of SSMS you're using, or that Object Explorer is connected as a different user than your query window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain why your context menu for the view doesn't show a Properties option (honestly relying on the GUI for this kind of thing is full of peril).

Thankfully, you can grant access to the view in a query window, no pointy-clicky dialogs required:

```
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.viw_Intake_Admin_Forms TO <phpusername>;
```